# Why are the XML ID name conventions different from the Java one's?

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions, butterknife

I looked at several Android projects. Why is it common practice to use lowercase with underscores for XML IDs?

in XML:

```
@+id/name_text <!-- sometimes with "_view" suffix, sometimes without -->
```

in Java:

```
TextView nameTextView = // ...
```

I would propose the following ID: `@+id/nameTextView`

That is actually how I do it. What would be the downside?

Especially data binding could be done even shorter (for example with ButterKnife) if the XML ID and field name would follow the same pattern. In this case we could just omit the XML ID in the annotation:

```
@BindView TextView nameTextView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature for Java yet, but for Kotlin: [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html).

If your view is declared like this (in *activity_main.xml*):

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
        />
```

you can work with it like this in your Activity:

```
hello.setText("Hi!")
```

---

The only thing that has to be done for this is to add this to the Kotlin file where you want to use the view:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

and of course adding the dependency in your project-local build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```